# new attributes of media in responsive.css no effect

Tags: css, responsive-design

Hello I hope you can answer my question,

My problem is that my responsive.css isn't responding, I edited the media queries, I added new attributes for it but it didn't show when I inspect element using firebug, what's wrong with this ?

thanks in advance !

Comment: show your media queries.

Comment: @media (max-width:320px) 
{#promo {
 float:left;
 }
 nav{width: 90%;}

 nav ul li a{width: 83%;}
}

this is the original media max-width 320,, 

and now I added new 3 attributes ,, 
 #banner{margin: auto;
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 78%;
                height: 229px;
                width: 100%;
                float:left!important;}
        .footer-links {margin-bottom: 20px;
     padding-left: 7%;
     text-align: left!important;
     width: 100%;
 }
 this is now the final css for media 320 ,, but when I inspect using firebug,, the 3 attributes didn't shown ,, why?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your code have formatted like below.

```
 @media (max-width:320px) 
 { 
 #promo{float:left;}
 nav{width:90%;} 
 nav ul li a{width:83%;} 
 #banner{margin:auto; float:none; position:relative; margin-top:78%; height:229px; width:100%; float:left !important;} 
 .footer-links {margin-bottom:20px; padding-left:7%; text-align:left!important; width:100%;}
 }
```

Comment: I do the same format like that but when I use to paste all attributes in my media to see what it looks like,, the comment box limited only a few characters that's why I compressed it, but thank you by the way :)